# Resources recommandation of probablity theory without measure theory which is suitable for machine learning?

Tags: probability, reference-request, conditional-expectation, machine-learning, online-resources

When I finished a course learning elementary probability as a student majoring in computer science, I try to dive into machine learning theory. However, I find my knowledge acquring from the probability lesson is not enough.

Many occasions the machine learning theory deals with the conditional expectation and concentration inequalities(for example: Chernoff bound).And I find the conditional expectation and concentration inequalities related knowledge is especially important in machine learning(especially: law of total expectation).However, in my class, we covered none of these knowledge.

Also, few books on probability will mention these things. Can anyone recommand some resources(such as lecture notes, textbooks and so on) which deal with these things in detail? (My background is only with calculus 1 2 3 and linear algebra(our textbooks even without SVD) and elementary probability)

Comment: Unfortunately, modern Probability Theory is founded on Measure Theory, so you will not find many good resources on probability theory that dispense of measure theory. However, the two very classical books of William Feller (both are named "An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications") contain a lot of useful information on  probability theory and the author makes sure that measure theory does not get too much on the way of _intuitively understanding what's going on._ You could check those...

Comment: ...Note however that Feller's books are 70 years old now! So they talk very little of Applications on computer science, and many of the examples feel old. In fact, some of Feller's examples are about telephone lines when at the time there was an operator physically connecting the lines. At any rate, most of the basic material of probability theory is included there and Feller is an excellent expositor and makes sure the book is accessible for all sorts of audiences. Other very good authors of probability include Robert Ash and Leo Breiman (the latter is active in Machine Learning).

Answer (score 1):

Concentration inequalities are hit or miss, but the below is a nice, non measure theoretic coverage of conditional expectation and probability in general (but at a much higher level than Intro to Probability):

[https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/BPT/BPTCh4.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Er-ash/BPT/BPTCh4.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I find Prof.Ash's book is really suitable for me.

Comment: @UESTCfresh I really like this book -- and it has answers in the back!